# RuntimeError: Too many failed attempts to build

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-tuner

**I want to use Keras tuner to tune model hyperparameter using the following code that first creates the class to make the optimization as following**

```
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filter=hp.Int('conv_1_filter',min_value=32,max_value=128,step=16),
                                                  kernel_size=hp.Choice('conv_1_kernel',values = [3,5]),
                                                  activation='relu',
                                                  input_shape=(28,28,1)
                                                  ))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filter=hp.Int('conv_2_filter',min_value=32,max_value=128,step=16),
                                                  kernel_size=hp.Choice('conv_2_kernel',values = [3,5]),
                                                  activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(
                                  units=hp.Int('dense_1_units',min_value=32,max_value=128, step=16),
                                  activation='relu'
                              ))
    model.add(layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(
            hp.Choice('learning_rate',
                      values=[1e-2, 1e-3])),
        loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

from kerastuner import RandomSearch
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from kerastuner.engine.hyperparameters import HyperParameters

tuner_search=RandomSearch(build_model,
                          objective='val_accuracy',
                          max_trials=5,
                          executions_per_trial=3,
                          directory='output',project_name='MNIST')
```

**
i run the class , but when i try to use any tuners such as random search, hyperband,etc. I got the following error
**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 105, in build
    model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
  File "<ipython-input-37-8db271052e01>", line 6, in build_model
    input_shape=(28,28,1)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filters'
[Warning] Invalid model 0/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 105, in build
    model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
  File "<ipython-input-37-8db271052e01>", line 6, in build_model
    input_shape=(28,28,1)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filters'
[Warning] Invalid model 1/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 105, in build
    model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
  File "<ipython-input-37-8db271052e01>", line 6, in build_model
    input_shape=(28,28,1)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filters'
[Warning] Invalid model 2/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 105, in build
    model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
  File "<ipython-input-37-8db271052e01>", line 6, in build_model
    input_shape=(28,28,1)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filters'
[Warning] Invalid model 3/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 105, in build
    model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
  File "<ipython-input-37-8db271052e01>", line 6, in build_model
    input_shape=(28,28,1)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filters'
[Warning] Invalid model 4/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py", line 105, in build
    model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
  File "<ipython-input-37-8db271052e01>", line 6, in build_model
    input_shape=(28,28,1)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filters'
[Warning] Invalid model 5/5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py in build(self, hp)
    104                 with maybe_distribute(self.distribution_strategy):
--> 105                     model = self.hypermodel.build(hp)
    106             except:

8 frames
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filters'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/kerastuner/engine/hypermodel.py in build(self, hp)
    113                 if i == self._max_fail_streak:
    114                     raise RuntimeError(
--> 115                         'Too many failed attempts to build model.')
    116                 continue
    117 

RuntimeError: Too many failed attempts to build model.
```

**
Can anyone plese help me to solve this.
**

Comment: please post more of the code.  what is ```build_model```?

Comment: assuming the code above the imports builds the build_model,  you're missing the ```filters``` parameter in your ```conv2D``` calls.

Answer (score 1):

So you have done most of the things correct, you have just made typo in your code.

You have to use `filters` and you have used `filter`.

Just to make it more clear it should be in the following way.

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=hp.Int('conv_1_filter',min_value=32,max_value=128,step=16),
                                                  kernel_size=hp.Choice('conv_1_kernel',values = [3,5]),
                                                  activation='relu',
                                                  input_shape=(28,28,1)
                                                  ))
```

Changing that should resolve the issue. I hope your issue gets resolved.